# How to fetch woocommerce product short description using wpdb query?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to fetch the woocommerce product short description using the wpdb query can anyone tell me how to do so?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`the_excerpt`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_excerpt) to get the **Short Description**.

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array( 'post_type' => 'product','post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => '-1' ) );

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
    the_excerpt();
endwhile;
```

So it will give you the **Short Description** if product have a short description.If not, then it will show you post content.

Comment: you can access short description using: `$wpdb->posts.post_excerpt`